# Wavesurfer.js : waveform width

Tags: wavesurfer.js

Is there an efficient way to change a wave width ?
I'd like to make the wave smaller and the option **minPxPerSec** is working until a certain value,
bellow that value the wave have the same width, as if there was a threshold
( unless the option **fillParent** is set to false, but it's make the wave truncated ).

edit : [here is an exemple of truncated waveform](https://codepen.io/M00NBOY/pen/ZVRxwZ?editors=0111)
as you can hear and see, the wave is finish before the audio

```
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: '#waveform',
  fillParent: false,
  minPxPerSec: 10, 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I find how to change the wave width, it is pretty simple in fact :
set fillParent to true, give the minPxPerSec that you want, and change the container width !